# How to implement MVVM architecture when using TextView to display Seekbar value after it is changed by user interaction?

Tags: java, android, mvvm

Right now I have a seekbar which has a onseekbarchangelistener attached to it which changes the value of a TextView(targetTemperature) every time the seekbar moves.

```
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
         Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: progress: " + progress);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                float addTo18 = ((float)progress) / 2;
                Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: addTo18 " + addTo18);
                if(MainActivity.selectedThermostat.getValue().getIsCelsius())
                    targetTemperature.setText(Float.toString((float) (18.0 + addTo18))); //u2109 for farenheit
                else
                    targetTemperature.setText(Float.toString((float) (64.0 + addTo18))); //u2109 for farenheit
            } else {
                if(MainActivity.selectedThermostat.getValue().getIsCelsius()) {
                    float addTo18 = (float) ((float) progress - 18.0) / 2;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: addTo18 " + addTo18);
                    targetTemperature.setText(String.valueOf(18.0 + addTo18)); //u2109 for farenheit
                } else {
                    float addTo18 = (float) ((float) progress - 64.0) / 2;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: addTo18 " + addTo18);
                    targetTemperature.setText(String.valueOf(64.0 + addTo18)); //u2109 for farenheit
                }
            }
        }
```

After reading through some articles on MVVM, I saw that changes to views(TextViews, ImageViews, etc.) in an activity come from observing changes to the mutable live data objects in the view model.

In that case, would it be better practice to create a mutable live data object in the viewmodel  and make changes to that instead of making changes to the TextView(targetTemperature) directly.

Essentially

User interaction -> seekbar change -> textView change

or

User interaction -> seekbar change -> change mutable live data in view model -> textview change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only UI change, then modifying the textView directly is fine.

However usually when user inputs something you will want to use it somewhere else other than the UI itself, so the safe way is the second one.

Except, I wouldn't expose MutableLiveData from the ViewModel, instead have a method something like onTemperatureChanges(value: Int) and the ViewModel does the calculation, has a private MutableLiveData and exposes a LiveData via a getter.

So it would look something like this:
View

```
viewModel.getTemperature().observe(lifecycleObserver, new Observer<String>() {
  @Override
  void onChanged(String text) {
    targetTemperature.setText(text)
  }
);

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
  Log.d(TAG, "onProgressChanged: progress: " + progress);
  viewModel.onTemperatureChanges(progress)
}
```

viewModel:

```
private MutableLiveData<String> temperature;

LiveData<String> getTemperature() {
  return temperature;
}

void onTemperatureChanges(int progress) {
  // not really sure why you depend on os version or if this calculation is correct, so I just add one section of it
  if (true == isCelsius.getValue()) { // isCelsius another livedata, which you update based on the UI
    temperature.setValue(String.valueOf(((float) progress - 18.0) / 2 + 18.0));
  } else {
    temperature.setValue(String.valueOf(((float) progress - 64.0) / 2 + 64.0));
  }
}
```

The basic idea is that the View (Activity or Fragment etc) should just delegate it's user inputs to the ViewModel and the ViewModel should do the calculations, data modifications etc, then expose a state via livedata (or flow) to the View which then updates based on that.

Sorry for my Java, i'm a bit out of touch with it lately.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follow:

your ViewModel class like this:

```
public class SeekViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public ObservableField<String> text = new ObservableField<>();

    public void onSeekBarChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        text.set("Your progress: " + progress);
    }
}
```

your xml layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.text}"
            />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onProgressChanged="@{viewModel.onSeekBarChanged}"
            android:max="10"
            android:progress="1"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Activity class do like this:

```
mActivityBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SeekViewModel.class);
        mActivityBinding.setViewModel(viewModel);
```